# Loop through modelica array fails

Tags: modelica

I am using openmodelica and I am trying to loop through an array in order to find the maximum value.  I was able to reduce my code to a very simple test case that still gives the error.  Is this something that I am doing wrong, or is this a bug in openmodelica? Here is a very simple case that does give the error:

```
package TestLoop
  model ItemA
    Real p;
  end ItemA;

  model ItemB
    ItemA a[n];
    parameter Integer n = 5;
    Real p;
  equation
    for i in 1:n loop
      a[i].p = time;
    end for;
  algorithm
    for i in 1:n loop
      p := a[i].p;
    end for;
  end ItemB;
end TestLoop;
```

The problem is in my algorithm section.  Here is the error that I am getting:

```
TestLoop.ItemB.c:155:13: warning: implicit declaration of function '$Pa$lB' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
      $Pp = $Pa$lB(modelica_integer)$Pi$rB$Pp;
            ^
TestLoop.ItemB.c:155:20: error: unexpected type name 'modelica_integer': expected expression
      $Pp = $Pa$lB(modelica_integer)$Pi$rB$Pp;
                   ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Any suggestions for why this might be, or how I can work around it?  If I replace the assignment with a fixed value, p:=a[1].p;, the code does run (although that is not useful to me).  What I ultimately want to do in the algorithm section is find the largest value of a[n].p, where I do have an equation section that does useful calculations into the array of items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the code generation is an error of OpenModelica (it does not like unknown array indexes). Your problem is very easy to solve in a single line though (one of the following):

```
p = max(r for r in a.p);
p = max(a.p);
```

Comment: Also described in the Section 10.3.4 Reduction Functions and Operators of the Modelica Specification: https://www.modelica.org/documents/ModelicaSpec33.pdf#page=113

Comment: I was also looking to find the index of the max as well.  Your suggestion pointed me in the right direction for that as well.    
`model ItemC
  ItemA a[n];
  parameter Integer n = 5;
  Real p;
  Integer n2;
  Real p2[n];
equation
  for i in 1:n loop
    a[i].p = time / i;
  end for;
algorithm
  p2 := vector(a.p);
  n2 := 0;
  p := 0;
  for i in 1:n loop
    if p2[i] > p then
      n2 := i;
      p := p2[i];
    end if;
  end for;
end ItemC;`